# Json data type response of IP rate limit API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-2.0

I am using middleware provided by [AspNetCoreRateLimit](https://github.com/stefanprodan/AspNetCoreRateLimit) to rate limit incoming requests to an ASP.NET Core 2.x REST API web application.

Currently this library returns html responses for rejected requests. How can I make it return json responses instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could custom your response in the `IpRateLimitMiddleware`.

`IpRateLimitMiddleware`

```
public class MyIpRateLimitMiddleware : IpRateLimitMiddleware
{
    public MyIpRateLimitMiddleware(RequestDelegate next
        , IOptions<IpRateLimitOptions> options
        , IRateLimitCounterStore counterStore
        , IIpPolicyStore policyStore
        , IRateLimitConfiguration config
        , ILogger<IpRateLimitMiddleware> logger) 
            : base(next, options, counterStore, policyStore, config, logger)
    {
    }

    public override Task ReturnQuotaExceededResponse(HttpContext httpContext, RateLimitRule rule, string retryAfter)
    {
        //return base.ReturnQuotaExceededResponse(httpContext, rule, retryAfter);
        var message = new { rule.Limit, rule.Period, retryAfter };

        httpContext.Response.Headers["Retry-After"] = retryAfter;

        httpContext.Response.StatusCode = 200;
        httpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

        return httpContext.Response.WriteAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message));
    }
}
```

Configure the middlware in `Startup.cs`

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        //app.UseIpRateLimiting();
        app.UseMiddleware<MyIpRateLimitMiddleware>();
        //your rest middlware
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

*Read the [docs](https://github.com/stefanprodan/AspNetCoreRateLimit/wiki/IpRateLimitMiddleware#behavior)*

> If the request gets blocked then the client receives a text response like this:
>
> ```
> Status Code: 429
> Retry-After: 58
> Content: API calls quota exceeded! maximum admitted 2 per 1m.
> ```
>
> You can customize the response by changing these options `HttpStatusCode` and `QuotaExceededMessage`, ***if you want to implement your own response you can override the `IpRateLimitMiddleware.ReturnQuotaExceededResponse`***. The `Retry-After` header value is expressed in seconds. (emphasis mine)

Comment: i saw this line but how to override

Comment: Golden rule of programming: never use a library you don't understand. Read the documentation. Go look at the source code. If all else fails, you can ask the repo author/maintainer (but do your own research first).